# Why is date so slow?

Tags: bash

Anyone know a better way to do this were it is faster?  This currently is slow when pushing high lines per second to this script:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A clientarray
file=$1
timer=$2
e=$(date --date "now +$timer second" +%s)

while read line
do

    if [ -n "${clientarray[$line]}" ]; then
            let "clientarray[$line]=clientarray[$line]+1"
            echo "$line: ${clientarray[$line]}"

    elif [ -z "${clientarray[$line]}" ]; then
            clientarray[$line]=1
            echo "$line: ${clientarray[$line]}"

    fi
    if [ $(date +%s) -gt $e ]; then
                    e=$(date --date "now +$timer second" +%s)

    fi
done < <(tail -F $file | gawk -F"]" '/]/ {print $1}')
```

---

Here is an example of the lines:

```
someline]
someline2]
somethingidontwant
someline3]
somethingelseidontwant
someline4]
```

and to call the script:

```
bash script.sh somelogfile.log 1
```

If I comment out the if logic at the very end it goes really fast but with it the speed drops 2/3rds.  Tested it with pv:

(this is with the if logic):

```
ubuntu@myhost:~/graphs$ tail -F somelogfile.log | pv -N RAW -lc >/dev/null | 
                      > bash script.sh somelogfile.log 1 | pv -N SCP -lc >/dev/null

  RAW: 2.18k 0:00:16 [ 493/s ] [                 <=>                             ]
  SCP:  593 0:00:16 [ 150/s ] [             <=>                                  ]
```

(this is without)

```
ubuntu@myhost:~/graphs$ tail -F somelogfile.log | pv -N RAW -lc >/dev/null |
                      > bash script.sh somelogfile.log 1 | pv -N SCP -lc >/dev/null

  RAW: 7.69k 0:00:15 [512/s] [                                     <=>           ]
  SCP:  7.6k 0:00:15 [503/s] [                              <=>                  ]
```

Let me know if I am missing something on my script or testing side, especially any "DOH!"'s.
I think at this point I would love one =)

Comment: You are reading `$line` but not using it in the code shown.  Is that an artefect of stripping the code down to a minimal reproduction?  Similarly, you aren't doing anything with `$e` except updating it periodically.  The fact that you have to run an external command (`date`) on each iteration will always make the process slower than when you have only internal commands to execute.  Ultimately, you may be better off using Python or Perl or something similar; it can avoid the new process overhead while doing the date calculations more simply in the first place.

Comment: fixed it, sorry about that I generally use i in place of line I just put line as that is the common example used for while read's and missed changing the body of the script.

Comment: It's a good idea to practice writing code so you won't want to modify it before you post it in public.  Then you don't get into problems like that.

Comment: I agree but its more of a lazy thing then anything...i is 3 letters shorter then line :)

Comment: The alternative is not to be worried about your coding standards and just publish with `i`.  I wouldn't have commented on it.  Modifying your code before publishing it is the problem; it's hard to get the changes right consistently if you've not run the modified code.  (I know; I make the mistake sometimes too.  We're all human.  Well, all except the cyborgs lurking on the 'net!)

Comment: I completely agree except I work with sensitive info I can't post so I always have to go over it or be worried about losing my job if I accidently post the wrong thing like a client name or specific piece of code.

Comment: Use `date -f - +%s`  as *background process*  then iterate with him with `echo` and `read`!  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195703/1765658)! Try it and comment!

Answer (score 2):

As a guess, I'd say it could be that that last `if`...`fi` block adds two non-builtin commands per iteration. Everything else in the loop is bash builtins, which execute much faster. With it, you have a call to `date` within the test, and another in the body of the `if`. In addition, `date --date` has to parse and evaluate that `"now +$timer second"` expression each time it's called, which probably isn't very speedy, given `--date`'s generality. If I were you, I'd try reimplementing this in a scripting language with more native handling of dates/times: Perl, Ruby, Python, whatever you're comfortable with.

You also appear to have a bug:

```
if [ `date +%s` > $e ] ...
```

This says: execute the command `date +%s` and interpolate its output (say `12345`) into another command `[ 12345 > $e ]` (so far so good). That command says: run the `[` builtin with two arguments (`12345` and `]`), and redirect its standard output stream to a file named by the value of `$e` (uh-oh). You probably want to use `-gt` instead of `>` here.

Comment: Or use `[[ $(date +%s) > $e ]]` (where the double brackets are the significant part, though avoiding backquotes and using `$(...)` is also good advice, doubly so when writing shell script in SO comments).

Comment: ...except that in that case `>` sorts lexicographically instead of numerically. So if the number of seconds since the epoch gains a digit while you're running this program (admittedly very unlikely) you're hosed ;-)

Comment: Might the usage of `time`, which is a buildin, instead of `date`, help? I don't really understood what the script does, but it seems to do some sort of timing. :)

Comment: `time` doesn't give you what time it is, but rather how much time a command takes to execute (in various senses). For example, `time sleep 1` should tell you that `sleep 1` takes about 1 second of real time to complete, and almost no system or user-mode time.

Comment: Ya my mistake I actually meant -gt not >, also I always use the $() I was just being lazy :)!  Made changes to the question.  The script goes through and counts a specific filtered item out of a log file.  The array is because there is few of them all within the same period of time.  Its really a bummer that this can't be done in bash, which language would be the fastest results for this sort of thing?

Comment: I thought there was someway to call up machine time quickly within bash, what type of time does not matter as long as it is 1 second later to compare against.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing with `$e`, but you can print the current date using the shell builtin `printf` much faster than you can by calling out to `date`. Subprocess calls tend to be expensive. For example, if you are not on glibc2 you can do:

```
printf '%(%+)T\n' -1
```

to get exactly the output of the date command. `%+` is not supported on glibc2 so you can construct something identical with other parameters, or something similar with:

```
printf '%(%c %Z)T\n' -1
```

If you need to capture and process the date somehow then you may still need a subshell call using `$()` but there's a decent chance it's still faster than `date`.