# Convert date time string to epoch in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, date

The date time string is in the following format: 06/12/2012 07:21:22. How can I convert it to UNIX timestamp or epoch?

Answer (score 128):

What you're looking for is `date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%s"`. Keep in mind that this assumes you're using GNU coreutils, as both `--date` and the `%s` format string are GNU extensions. POSIX doesn't specify either of those, so there is no portable way of making such conversion even on POSIX compliant systems.

Consult the appropriate manual page for other versions of `date`.

Note: bash `--date` and `-d` option expects the date in US or ISO8601 format, i.e. `mm/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy-mm-dd`, not in UK, EU, or any other format.

Comment: I get 'date: illegal option --' when I run on Mac OSX 10.8.2

Comment: For noobs like me `+"%s"` stands for output format and `%s` is the format of time in seconds since 1970

Comment: Note: if you want to specify the time in another timezone (like UTC) add -HHMM or +HHMM to the end. So `date --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22 -0000' +"%s"` converts UTC date to unix time stamp

Comment: For GNU date, if you wish to use UTC note that the format is `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`have a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html : `gdate --date='2019-06-18 00:02:00 +0000' +%s`

Comment: doesn't work on a Mac... I wonder if there is a way to work both on a Mac and Linux

Comment: @nonopolarity You can [install GNU utilities on a mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332/42929), then it'll work. A number of other GNU utilities are handy too (eg: gnu grep, which accepts perl regexes)

Comment: @nonopolarity On my mac with gnu coreutils, the command is called `gdate` instead of date.  I can run the above command from @Daniel Kamil Kozar using:  ```gdate --date='06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%s"``` which in turn gives me:
`1339510882`

Comment: @Ben Clayton and others: on macOS, you can use `date -j -f %Y-%m-%d 2022-09-27 +%s`

Answer (score 85):

For Linux, run this command:

```
date -d '06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%s"
```

For macOS, run this command:

```
date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "1970-01-01 00:00:00" +%s
```

Comment: On OSX the timestamp increases somehow with the current time. I currently don't have an explanation for that...

Comment: Update: That was because it adjusts the timestamp for my localtime I guess... Adding a `-u` flag should fix that.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanJanjua The `-u` flag should come **before** the `-f` flag, or else the shell interprets it the format string. So, it should be: `date -j -u -f "%a..."`

Comment: So, why doesn't `echo date -d '06/12/2012 07:21:22' +"%s"` output the date?

Comment: What if my time is in format `14. 10. 2016 20:22:57`, date says invalid time.

Comment: Pasting exactly that in a macOS terminal fails.

Comment: `date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "2018-01-08 14:45:00" +%s`

Comment: It fails with the `-u` option because that affects both input an output formats, and a format with `EDT` clearly is not UTF. Use `-u` if you are not specifying a timezone in your input. Epoch second (`%s`) does not use timezones.

Answer (score 16):

A lot of these answers overly complicated and also missing how to use variables. This is how you would do it more simply on standard Linux system (as previously mentioned the date command would have to be adjusted for Mac Users) :

Sample script:

```
#!/bin/bash
orig="Apr 28 07:50:01"
epoch=$(date -d "${orig}" +"%s")
epoch_to_date=$(date -d @$epoch +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)    

echo "RESULTS:"
echo "original = $orig"
echo "epoch conv = $epoch"
echo "epoch to human readable time stamp = $epoch_to_date"
```

Results in :

```
RESULTS:
original = Apr 28 07:50:01
epoch conv = 1524916201 
epoch to human readable time stamp = 20180428_075001
```

Or as a function :

```
# -- Converts from human to epoch or epoch to human, specifically "Apr 28 07:50:01" human.
#    typeset now=$(date +"%s")
#    typeset now_human_date=$(convert_cron_time "human" "$now")

function convert_cron_time() {
    case "${1,,}" in
        epoch)
            # human to epoch (eg. "Apr 28 07:50:01" to 1524916201)
            echo $(date -d "${2}" +"%s")
            ;;
        human)
            # epoch to human (eg. 1524916201 to "Apr 28 07:50:01")
            echo $(date -d "@${2}" +"%b %d %H:%M:%S")
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just be sure what timezone you want to use.

```
datetime="06/12/2012 07:21:22"
```

Most popular use takes machine timezone.

```
date -d "$datetime" +"%s" #depends on local timezone, my output = "1339456882"
```

But in case you intentionally want to pass UTC datetime and you want proper timezone you need to add `-u` flag. Otherwise you convert it from your local timezone.

```
date -u -d "$datetime" +"%s" #general output = "1339485682"
```

Comment: What if my date format is "YYYYmmdd"? 
ex. 20200827

Comment: You can use it as well. `date` formats properly this input.

Answer (score 6):

## Efficient way to convert *date time string* to *epoch* in bash

Avoiding *useless repetitives* forks, in order to make this translation a **lot quicker**...

Instead of running 1 fork for each translation, we could run `date -f - +%s` as background process...

### Intro

Common syntax:

```
epochDate=$(date -d "$InputDate" +%s)
```

Work fine, but become heavy if run repetetively!

In this post, you will find

- a *Quick Demo*, following this,
- some *Explanations*,
- a *Function* useable for many *Un*x* tools (`bc`, `rot13`, `sed`...).

#### Quick Demo

```
fifo=$HOME/.fifoDate-$$
mkfifo $fifo
exec 5> >(exec stdbuf -o0 date -f - +%s >$fifo 2>&1)
echo now 1>&5
exec 6< $fifo
rm $fifo
read -t 1 -u 6 now
echo $now
```

This must output current *UNIXTIME*. From there, you could compare

```
time for i in {1..5000};do echo >&5 "now" ; read -t 1 -u6 ans;done
real    0m0.298s
user    0m0.132s
sys     0m0.096s
```

and:

```
time for i in {1..5000};do ans=$(date +%s -d "now");done 
real    0m6.826s
user    0m0.256s
sys     0m1.364s
```

**From more than 6 seconds to less than a half second!!**(on my host).

You could check `echo $ans`, replace `"now"` by `"2019-25-12 20:10:00"` and so on...

Optionaly, you could, once requirement of *date subprocess* ended:

```
exec 5>&- ; exec 6<&-
```

### Original post (detailed explanation)

Instead of running 1 *fork* by date to convert, run `date` just 1 time and do all convertion with same process (this could become a lot quicker)!:

```
date -f - +%s <<eof
Apr 17  2014
May 21  2012
Mar  8 00:07
Feb 11 00:09
eof
1397685600
1337551200
1520464020
1518304140
```

Sample:

```
start1=$(LANG=C ps ho lstart 1)
start2=$(LANG=C ps ho lstart $$)
dirchg=$(LANG=C date -r .)
read -p "A date: " userdate
{ read start1 ; read start2 ; read dirchg ; read userdate ;} < <(
   date -f - +%s <<<"$start1"$'\n'"$start2"$'\n'"$dirchg"$'\n'"$userdate" )
```

Then now have a look:

```
declare -p start1 start2 dirchg userdate
```

> (may answer something like:

> ```
> declare -- start1="1518549549"
> declare -- start2="1520183716"
> declare -- dirchg="1520601919"
> declare -- userdate="1397685600"
> ```

This was done in one execution!

#### Using *long running* subprocess

We just need one *fifo*:

```
mkfifo /tmp/myDateFifo
exec 7> >(exec stdbuf -o0 /bin/date -f - +%s >/tmp/myDateFifo)
exec 8</tmp/myDateFifo
rm /tmp/myDateFifo
```

(Note: As process is running and all descriptors are opened, we could safely remove fifo's filesystem entry.)

Then now:

```
LANG=C ps ho lstart 1 $$ >&7
read -u 8 start1
read -u 8 start2
LANG=C date -r . >&7
read -u 8 dirchg

read -p "Some date: " userdate
echo >&7 $userdate
read -u 8 userdate
```

We could buid a little function:

```
mydate() {
    local var=$1;
    shift;
    echo >&7 $@
    read -u 8 $var
}

mydate start1 $(LANG=C ps ho lstart 1)
echo $start1
```

### Or use *my* `newConnector` function

With *functions* for *connecting* *`MySQL/MariaDB`*, *`PostgreSQL`* and *`SQLite`*...

You may find them in different version on [GitHub](https://github.com/F-Hauri/Connector-bash), or on my site: [download](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh) or [show](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh.txt).

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/F-Hauri/Connector-bash/master/shell_connector.bash
```

```
wget http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/shell_connector.sh
. shell_connector.bash 
newConnector /bin/date '-f - +%s' @0 0

myDate "2018-1-1 12:00" test
echo $test
1514804400
```

**Nota:** On *GitHub*, functions and test are separated files. On *my site* test are run simply if this script is not *sourced*. On *GitHub*, there is no upgrade anymore! Last verified version is on my site!

```
# Exit here if script is sourced
[ "$0" = "$BASH_SOURCE" ] || { true;return 0;}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
get_curr_date () {
    # get unix time
    DATE=$(date +%s)
    echo "DATE_CURR : "$DATE
}

conv_utime_hread () {
    # convert unix time to human readable format
    DATE_HREAD=$(date -d @$DATE +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
    echo "DATE_HREAD          : "$DATE_HREAD
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider adding an explanation in addition to your code.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following alias to `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`) - note the `--utc` switch which converts the input as UTC time zone. You can remove it to use the local machine time zone but in my experience I usually want UTC for this:

```
alias datetoepoch='date --utc +%s -d'
```

Now I can just type in the terminal something like:

```
datetoepoch 2024-03-18
```

and get the result:

> 1710720000