# Bash convert date to timestamp

Tags: bash, date, timestamp

I have a date in format `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'` and I need to convert it to Unix timestamp.

I tried to `date -d '20140826225834'` but I get `'invalid date'` error. I asume that I would have to convert what I have ( `20140826225834` ) to accepted date and then convert it to timestamp?
Edit: I have sed this date from `2014-08-21_23.03.07` - maybe it would be easier to convert this date type

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date time string to UNIX timestamp in bash command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-unix-timestamp-in-bash-command)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably change the format of the date you get, so that `date` can handle it. I change it to a `YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS` format with `sed`.

```
$ date -d"$(sed -r 's#(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})#\1/\2/\3 \4:\5:#' <<< "20140826225834")" "+%s"
1409086714
```

By pieces:

```
$ sed -r 's#(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})(.{2})#\1/\2/\3 \4:\5:#' <<< "20140826225834"
2014/08/26 22:58:34

$ date -d"2014/08/26 22:58:34"
Tue Aug 26 22:58:34 CEST 2014

$ date -d"2014/08/26 22:58:34" "+%s"
1409086714
```

Comment: +1 because `sed` will more likely being used in a shell script than PHP ;)

Comment: When I run the first piece (sed) I get `1409086714` - is this the timestamp?

Comment: @Lenny yes. UNIX timestamp is `seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP, since PHP's `strtotime()` can parse your input format:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="20140826225834"
output=$(php -r 'echo strtotime("'"$input"'");')

echo "$output" # 1409086714
```