# Convert time from dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss to unix timestamp in bash script

Tags: bash, datetime, awk

I have browsed through the similar threads and they helped me come closest to what I want to do but didn't fully answer my question.

I have a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` (`$mydate = 26/12/2013 09:42:42`) that I want to convert in unix timestamp via the command:

```
date -d $mydate +%s
```

But here the accepted format is this one: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

So I did this transformation:

```
echo $mydate| awk -F' ' '{printf $1}'| awk -F/ '{printf "%s-%s-%s\n",$3,$2,$1}'
```

And have this ouput:

```
2013-12-26
```

Which is good, now I try to append to hour part before doing the conversion:

```
echo $mydate| awk -F' ' '{printf $1; $hour=$2}'| awk -F/ '{printf "%s-%s-%s %s\n",$3,$2,$1,$hour}'
```

But then I have this:

```
2013-12-26 26/12/2013
```

It seem to not keep the variable `$hour`.

I am new in awk, how could I do this ?

Comment: Take a look that One http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619923/bash-convert-date-to-timestamp Hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk you can use a regex as a field separator. In your case instead of using awk twice you may want to do the following:

```
echo $mydate| awk -F' |/' '{printf "%s-%s-%s %s",$3,$2,$1,$4}'
```

With this we use both space and / as separators. First 3 parts are the date field, 4th one is time which lies after space.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. "The -F' |/' uses both space and / as separators" ==> perfect !

Comment: Good one! No need to split the time as I did.

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that you are "losing" the time block when you say `awk '{print $1}'`.

Instead, you can use a single `awk` command like:

```
awk -F'[: /]' '{printf "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", $3, $2, $1, $4, $5, $6}'
```

This slices the record based on either `:`, `/` or space and then puts them back together in the desired format.

Test:

```
$ echo "26/12/2013 09:42:42" | awk -F'[: /]' '{printf "%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", $3, $2, $1, $4, $5, $6}'
2013-12-26 9:42:42
```

Then store it in a var and use `date -d`: `formatted_date=$(awk '...'); date -d"$formatted_date"`.

Comment: This works too, thanks. Now I know one can use multiple separators at the same time in awk, awesome!