# Bash convert string to timestamp

Tags: bash, sh

I have a string in format `20141225093000` which represents `Dec 25, 2014 09:30:00` and I want to convert the original format to a unix timestamp format so i can do time operations on it.How would I do this in bash?

I can easily parse out the values with `expr` but I was hoping to be able to identify a format like YYYYmmddHHMMSS and then convert it based on that.

Comment: Any conversion is not performed by bash itself, but by your local `date` command. Are you targeting only platforms with GNU date, or do you need to support other, incompatible versions of `date` (such as MacOS's BSD-derived implementation)?

Comment: ...well, I say that; it's mostly true, but quite entirely: Very, _very_ new versions of bash have built-in date formatting, but if you need to support anything even slightly old it's not widespread/portable yet.

Answer (score 8):

With GNU date, you can convert `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` to epoch time (seconds since 1-1-1970) easily, like so:

```
date -d '2014-12-25T09:30:00' +%s
```

To do this starting without any delimiters:

```
in=20141225093000
rfc_form="${in:0:4}-${in:4:2}-${in:6:2}T${in:8:2}:${in:10:2}:${in:12:2}"
epoch_time=$(date -d "$rfc_form" +%s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform the string before calling `date`:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="20141225093000"
s=$(perl -pe 's/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6/g' <<< "$s")
date -d "$s" +%s
```

Yet another way:

```
perl -MDate::Parse -MPOSIX -le '$s="20141225093000"; $s =~ s/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6/g ; print str2time($s);'
1419499800
```

Comment: If you're going to use `perl`, why not do the whole thing there? That way you don't need to depend on GNU date (and will work on non-GNU platforms such as MacOS)... *and* Perl's date-time libraries will take a format string, so you can do the actual conversion in a shorter/more readable way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it could be done in `perl` but when I see `sh` `bash` tags I limit my perl commands to one-liner and avoid using non-core modules which may not be installed.

Comment: fair 'nuff, but if you're trying to honor the `bash` tag, none of the functionality you used in perl is anything bash doesn't already have built-in (there's already support for regular expressions with capture and group extraction via the `=~` operator and BASH_REMATCH).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Date::Parse and POSIX are core modules so I can use :)

Comment: +1; adds something new and useful to the other answers (by being something that'll work on systems with neither GNU date nor GNU awk). :)

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk:

```
gawk -v t=20141225093000 'BEGIN {gsub(/../, "& ", t); sub(/ /,"",t); print mktime(t)}'
```

If GNU date is not available, then it's likely GNU awk may not be. Perl probably has the highest chance of being available. This snippet uses `strptime` so you don't have to parse the time string at all:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -E 'say Time::Piece->strptime(shift, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")->epoch' 20141225093000
```

Comment: +1: Tooling with a reasonable chance of being installed in places where GNU date is not.

Answer (score 1):

This Bash function does the conversion with builtins:

```
# Convert UTC datetime string (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) to Unix epoch seconds
function ymdhms_to_epoch
{
    local -r ymdhms=${1//[!0-9]}    # Remove non-digits

    if (( ${#ymdhms} != 14 )) ; then
        echo "error - '$ymdhms' is not a valid datetime" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    # Extract datetime components, possibly with leading zeros
    local -r year=${ymdhms:0:4}
    local -r month_z=${ymdhms:4:2}
    local -r day_z=${ymdhms:6:2}
    local -r hour_z=${ymdhms:8:2}
    local -r minute_z=${ymdhms:10:2}
    local -r second_z=${ymdhms:12:2}

    # Remove leading zeros from datetime components to prevent them
    # being treated as octal values
    local -r month=${month_z#0}
    local -r day=${day_z#0}
    local -r hour=${hour_z#0}
    local -r minute=${minute_z#0}
    local -r second=${second_z#0}

    # Calculate Julian Day Number (jdn)
    # (See <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day>, Calculation)
    local -r -i a='(14-month)/12'
    local -r -i y=year+4800-a
    local -r -i m=month+12*a-3
    local -r -i jdn='day+(153*m+2)/5+365*y+(y/4)-(y/100)+(y/400)-32045'

    # Calculate days since the Unix epoch (1 Jan. 1970)
    local -r -i epoch_days=jdn-2440588

    local -r -i epoch_seconds='((epoch_days*24+hour)*60+minute)*60+second'

    echo $epoch_seconds

    return 0
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ ymdhms_to_epoch '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
0
$ ymdhms_to_epoch '2014-10-18 00:10:06'
1413591006
$ ymdhms_to_epoch '2014-12-25 09:30:00'
1419499800
```

Comment: Interesting. Have you compared results against a canonical implementation? I'm curious as to whether there are other factors such as leap seconds involved.

Comment: I compared the results of this implementation against GNU 'date' for a large number of random dates and times between 1970 and 2038 on a modern Linux system.  They all agreed.  The GNU 'date' documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Examples-of-date.html) suggests that most systems do not use leap seconds.  Even on a system that did use leap seconds, this implementation could be useful for the purposes suggested in the question.

Comment: You could shorten this by removing `var=${var#0}`  and prepend them by `10#`:  `declare -i v='36525*10#var'`

Comment: Btw, I use `date -S - +%s` for this! But as a background co-process:  [Convert date time string to epoch in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195703/1765658)