# Parse ISO date with older GNU coreutils

Tags: bash, shell, date, unix

I am parsing a date as below:

```
date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ' -d '2017-10-06T13:41:06Z'
```

It works fine with date version *(GNU coreutils) 8.21* but it is not working for date version *(GNU coreutils) 8.4*. Giving following error:

> date: invalid date `2017-10-06T13:41:06Z'

Is there a way to parse this date in *(GNU coreutils) 8.4* ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash convert string to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26432050/bash-convert-string-to-timestamp)

Comment: @pacholik No, that thread is about parsing a different format.

Comment: @Gilles Different format makes it different question?

Comment: @pacholik Depends. In this case, the set of solutions is very different, so yes. There isn't a single way to parse dates, so there can't be a single question on parsing dates.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you're using was [added in GNU coreutils 8.13](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/NEWS?id=c7fca77515cc0c55f2c47c9f18c313aaef80922c), so if you're using an older version, it isn't available.

Split the time at the `T` first. That works with older versions.

```
# Given an ISO date $iso_date with the time in split format HH:MM:SS...
date_part=${iso_date%%T*}
time_part=${iso_date#*T}
date -d "$date_part $time_part"
```

If you also need to support the condensed format with no punctuation, see [a similar question on Unix Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107750/how-to-parse-iso8601-dates-with-linux-date-command).

Comment: Given that the shell is Bash, one can simply substitute `T` with a space: `date -d "${iso_date/T/ }"`