# how to set string to timestamp in unix?

Tags: shell, date, unix, timestamp

I have a String variable in unix script having data like '`2017010110`' (format is like -- `%Y%m%d%H`). Please note that its not System timestamp.

Now I need to subtract -1 hour from `2017010110`. Means the output should be `2017010109`. I tried subtracting 1 from the variable.

But when the input is 2017010100, its obvious that I am gonna get wrong output `2017010099` (Expected output is `2016123123`).

Seems like I have to set my String variable to timestamp in unix to make this subtraction of 1 hour happen.

I referred [Convert date time string to UNIX timestamp in bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-unix-timestamp-in-bash-command) but couldn't find any luck.

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: DO you have a `GNU date` or a `FreeBSD date`?

Comment: Hello. GNU date is available. But I am not knowing how to set my string variable to date format for subtracting 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
ts="2017010100"
d="[0-9]"
if
  [[ "$ts" =~ ($d$d$d$d)($d$d)($d$d)($d$d) ]]
then
  year="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  month="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  day="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  hour="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
  timezone=EST
  adjusted_ts="$(date -d "$year-$month-$day $hour:00:00 $timezone - 1 hour" "+%Y%m%d%H")"
  echo "$adjusted_ts"
else
  echo "Invalid timestamp"
fi
```

This code splits your timestamp into individual fields, feeds GNU `date` with a time format it understand and removes one hour, and sets a variable to the output of this `date` command.  The code is Bash-specific (using Bash regex matching), but it gives you a general idea.

Please note I have been forced to specify a timezone, or else (at least on my system) there is some kind of offset (probably related to UTC) that messes up the result.  I have not found a way to specify some kind of "LOCAL" timezone that would avoid having to embed the system timezone in the sting.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestion to improve this and make the code timezone-independent.