# Parse date/time in in Bash

Tags: string, bash, date, find

I'm having an issue while trying to parse a date/time string in inside the find function. Anybody has any idea how to solve this?
Many thanks.

```
src_dir="/Users/user/directory/subdirectory"

start_dt='2018-08-15'
end_dt='2018-08-21'


find src_dir -name "*.txt" -newermt start_dt ! -newermt end_dt -exec ls -l "{}" \;
```

> > > Result:
> > >       "
> > >       find: Can't parse date/time: start_dt
> > >       "

Comment: To get the value of a variable, precede it with `$`. It's also generally a good idea to put double-quotes around it in case it contains whitespace or wildcards, as in `find "$src_dir" -name "*.txt" -newermt "$start_dt" ! -newermt "$end_dt" -exec ls -l "{}" \;`

Comment: Hi, many thanks! Your suggestion did work for me.. I just had to precede the variables Start_dt and End_dt with "$".                   start_dt='2018-08-15'
end_dt='2018-08-21'

find src_dir -name "*.txt" -newermt $start_dt ! -newermt $end_dt -exec ls -l "{}" \;

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the "date strings" to timestamps.  Try

```
start_dt=`date --date='2018-08-15' +%s`
end_dt=`date --date='2018-08-21' +%s`
```

This was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-epoch-in-bash)

Comment: When using the `-newermt` comparisons, a date format of `"yyyy-mm-dd"` is correct, no need to convert to seconds since epoch.