# Bash: Calculate the time differences in hours from input like "YYYYMMDDHH"

Tags: bash, date

I have two dates in forms like: `YYYYMMDDHH` and want to calculate the differences (in hours) between these two dates. For example

```
start_date=1996010100
end_date=1996010122
```

which stands for two dates: 1996-01-01 00:00:00 and 1996-01-01 22:00:00. I want to use `date` to calculate the difference in hours, the result shall be 22 hours. I tried with

```
START=$(date -d "$start_date" +"%s")
END=$(date -d "$end_date" +"%s")
HOURS=$(bc -l <<< "($END - $START) / 3600")
```

but it failed...
So how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: please update the question to explain *'it failed'*; also update the question with the expected results for the sample inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performance reasons we want to limit the number of sub-process calls we need to invoke:

- use `bash` substring functionality to convert inputs into usable date/time strings
- use `bash` math to replace `bc` call

`bash` substring functionality to break the inputs into a usable date/time format, eg:

```
# convert to usable date/time format:

$ start_date=1996010100
$ echo "${start_date:0:4}-${start_date:4:2}-${start_date:6:2} ${start_date:8:2}:00:00"
1996-01-01 00:00:00

# convert to epoch/seconds:

$ start=$(date -d "${start_date:0:4}-${start_date:4:2}-${start_date:6:2} ${start_date:8:2}:00:00" +"%s")
$ echo $start
820476000
```

Applying to `${end_date}` and using `bash` math:

```
$ end_date=1996010122
$ end=$(date -d "${end_date:0:4}-${end_date:4:2}-${end_date:6:2} ${end_date:8:2}:00:00" +"%s")
$ echo $end
820555200

$ hours=$(( (end - start) / 3600))
$ echo $hours
22
```

This leaves us with 2 sub-process calls (`$(date ...)`). While other languages/tools (`awk`, `perl`, etc) can likely speed this up a bit, if you need to store the result in a `bash` variable then you're looking at needing at least 1 sub-process call (ie, `hours=$(awk/perl/??? ...)`).

If performance is really important (eg, needing to perform this 1000's of times) take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49195703) that uses a fifo, background `date` process and io redirection ... yeah, a bit more coding and a bit more convoluted but also a bit faster for large volumes of operations.

Comment: You might want to add a function: `to_epoch() { date -d "${1:0:4}-${1:4:2}-${1:6:2} ${1:8:2}:00:00" '+%s'; }`

Answer (score 2):

`busybox date` can do the trick

```
start_date=1996010100
end_date=1996010122

START=$(busybox date -D "%Y%m%d%H" -d "$start_date" +"%s")
END=$(busybox date -D "%Y%m%d%H" -d "$end_date" +"%s")
HOURS=$(bc -l <<< "scale=0;($END - $START) / 3600")
echo $HOURS
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible for you to use a more fully-featured scripting language like Python, it'll provide a much more pleasant and understandable date parsing experience, and is probably installed by default (`datetime` is also a standard Python library)

Structured with shell vars

```sh
start_date=1996010100
end_date=1996010122
python -c "import datetime ; td = datetime.datetime.strptime('${end_date}', '%Y%m%d%H') - datetime.datetime.strptime('${start_date}', '%Y%m%d%H') ; print(int(td.total_seconds() / 3600))"
```

Structured to read dates and format code from `stdin`

```sh
echo '%Y%m%d%H' 1996010100 1996010122 | python -c "import datetime,sys ; fmt, date_start, date_end = sys.stdin.read().strip().split() ; td = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_end, fmt) - datetime.datetime.strptime(date_start, fmt) ; print(int(td.total_seconds() / 3600))"
```

Should work with both Python 3 and Python 2.7

format codes available here (1989 C standard)
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Answer (score 1):

> which stands for two dates: 1996-01-01 00:00:00

So convert it to that form if it stands for it.

```
start_date=1996010100
start_date=$(sed -E 's/(....)(..)(..)(..)/\1-\2-\3 \4:00:00/' <<<"$start_date")
start=$(date -d "$start_date" +"%s")
```

and the same with end.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, thanks for your quick answer! But is there a faster way to convert the ```start_date``` from YYYYMMDDHH to the format which we want? I see that this command costs ~1 second...by the way, I saw the final result is ```22.00000000000000000000```, can we put it in an int form? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, move to python or perl. For even faster, move to C++ or Rust. Bash is slow. `this command costs ~1 second` Note that `date` is _very_ slow, it does a lot behind scenes. `sed` should be fast. Still 1 second to spawn some process is ridiculously high, I would suggest inspecting your system for problems. `can we put it in an int form?` `bc` has `scale` option, but just use shell arithemtic.

Comment: Hi @KamilCuk, can I ask, what if I want to add "UTC" to calculate it in the UTC time zone?

Comment: ? Then add UTC to do that.

Comment: So just ```start=$(date -d "$start_date UTC" +"%s")```?

Comment: Yes, sure. ____

Answer (score 1):

the most simple way is to install "dateutils" using this command

```
sudo apt-get install dateutils
```

Run these commands to get the difference in seconds:

```
dateutils.ddiff -i '%Y%m%d%H%M%S' 20200817040001 20210817040101
```

output:

```
31536060s
```

next step: Simply divide by 86400 to get the number of days or similarly for hours and minutes :)

Comment: Thanks! But I am on a server where I was not able to use "sudo"...

Comment: I think it will also work if you do not use sudo.