# more efficient HH:MM:SS conversion possible?

Tags: python, bash, perl, time

I'm wondering please if there is a more efficient way to convert HH:MM:SS to decimal hours for the ordinate (y) axis of gnuplot, with dates on the (x) abscissa. Some of these plots have many thousands of data points and take much time to convert the hours to decimal.

A data set (/tmp/fn) looks like:

```
...
2022 Aug 21 05:35:16
2022 Aug 22 14:53:33
2022 Aug 31 14:11:55
2022 Sep 03 18:24:29
2022 Sep 03 18:24:56
2022 Sep 04 06:55:29
2022 Sep 04 06:55:44
2022 Sep 05 16:01:57
2022 Sep 05 16:02:16
2022 Sep 06 04:20:26
...
```

My current method is bash shell with:

```
...
# change HH:MM:SS to "d"ecimal hours
for t in $(awk '{print $NF}' /tmp/fn)
do 
  read H M S < <(echo $t | sed 's|:| |g')
  d=$(echo "scale=4; $H + $M/60 + $S/3600" | bc 2>/dev/null)
  sed -i "s|$t|$d|g" /tmp/fn
done
...
```

[edit]Sorry, I thought the simple sed construct indicated the desired output:

```
...
2022 Aug 21 5.5877
2022 Aug 22 14.8924
...
```

[/edit]

It would be very helpful if this could be made more efficient and less time-consuming, as a datafile with 9k entries consumes about 42 secs for the conversion, and much larger datasets are possible.

python or perl expressions are also welcomed. Thank you for your considerations.

Comment: What do you want to convert the times into? Give the expected output for that sample input.

Comment: @Shawn --  Based on the code it looks like `2022 Aug 22 14.8924` is the desired output type

Comment: you could make an integer out of all the numbers `2022 Aug 21 05:35:16` = `20220921053516` or you can use an `epoch` time.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, decimal hours are desired, as previously stated. The bash code I posted outputs correctly, just seeking greater efficiency.

Comment: I think that the loop is where your slowdown is .. You have to read each line in, then fork and do your replacement.   Not saying there isn't a better way, but this is how I would have attacked it.  You're reading 9k lines one-by-one and using a `sed` that still needs forked to convert the time ..  Seems pretty efficient to me ... And the 42 seconds is expected for 9k lines.  I may be wrong, but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: [shell - Convert date time string to epoch in Bash - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-epoch-in-bash) - it uses command `date` for this.

Comment: How can a question _that doesn't even specify a single implementation language_ be narrow or specific? Failing to lock down tool choice leaves this question deeply open-ended.

Comment: ...that said, if you want to make native bash efficient, _don't ever start subprocesses inside inner loops_. `$()` is a subprocess. A pipe is a subprocess. Any executable starts a subprocess. _Don't do those things_ when you care about efficiency. Your code may still be slower than native awk, perl or Python after you've made those changes, but it'll still be orders of magnitude faster than what you have now.

Comment: @furas, ...we don't necessarily want to call `date` in a loop, though. That's a `fork()` and an `execve()` at minimum, not to mention the `mkfifo()` needed to set up for capturing stdout, etc etc.

Comment: @dwarnok To be clear, `awk` and `bc` and so forth are fine _if you have only one copy running for the whole input stream_; it's running them once per item in your inputs that is absolutely unacceptable when performance is something you care about. (Part of what I'm trying to communicate here is that it's possible to write bash that performs reasonably, if you know how the code you write is executed and keep its costs in mind).

Comment: Does the time zone in question use DST? If so, your approach will give you values that are off by 0.0417 two days out of the year.

Comment: If you are worried about the amount of wall clock time due to the wast amount of data, it's odd that you want to do it in `bash` at all. Python and Perl make more sense. In any case, avoid creating child processes in your loop.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `perl` one-liner:

```bash
$ perl -pe 's{(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)$}{sprintf("%.4f", $1 + ($2/60.0) + ($3/3600.0))}e' fn.txt
2022 Aug 21 5.5878
2022 Aug 22 14.8925
2022 Aug 31 14.1986
2022 Sep 03 18.4081
2022 Sep 03 18.4156
2022 Sep 04 6.9247
2022 Sep 04 6.9289
2022 Sep 05 16.0325
2022 Sep 05 16.0378
2022 Sep 06 4.3406
```

If you want to modify the file directly and that's the desired format, add the `-i` option: `perl -pi -e ...`

Comment: Absolutely excellent, thank you! 5.7 secs instead of 42 for the base sample. The script including gnuplot graphic takes only 12.8 secs for 632,853 data points.

Answer (score 3):

I'm with dawg.
I really don't understand why you would explicitly use `awk` in your loop and not just do the entire task there.

```
$ awk -F'[: ]' '{ printf "%s %s %s %.4f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4+$5/60+$6/3600 }' file
2022 Aug 21 5.5878
2022 Aug 22 14.8925
2022 Aug 31 14.1986
2022 Sep 03 18.4081
2022 Sep 03 18.4156
2022 Sep 04 6.9247
2022 Sep 04 6.9289
2022 Sep 05 16.0325
2022 Sep 05 16.0378
2022 Sep 06 4.3406
```

Comment: @dwarnok would you mind posting the time taken to run this solution against your 632,853 data points input file for comparison with [your previously mentioned results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77602200/more-efficient-hhmmss-conversion-possible/77602599#comment136808801_77602325)?

Answer (score 2):

Elimate the Bash loop and do it in a simple scripting language.

Here is an awk:

```
awk '{split($NF,tm,":"); $NF=tm[1]+tm[2]/60+tm[3]/3600} 1' file
```

With your input:

```
2022 Aug 21 5.58778
2022 Aug 22 14.8925
2022 Aug 31 14.1986
2022 Sep 03 18.4081
2022 Sep 03 18.4156
2022 Sep 04 6.92472
2022 Sep 04 6.92889
2022 Sep 05 16.0325
2022 Sep 05 16.0378
2022 Sep 06 4.34056
```

Comment: i have never seen this 'language' before.  interesting. (i posted the python solutions)...

Comment: You have never seen awk? It is the elegant grandaddy of all! And best of all, it is on almost every Bash in the universe. Read an [intro](https://learnbyexample.github.io/learn_gnuawk/awk-introduction.html). Love Python btw, but it is a little harder for 1 line shell use. Awk, Perl, Ruby have a more natural stdin interface...

Comment: i noted that one of the answers was a `perl` post too. again done in one line...  we learn something new every day.

Comment: As the English say 'horses for courses' - Python is fabulous for something kinda structured and big; Perl is expressive and goofy; awk is the best for a quick program that works everywhere; Ruby is the structure of Python with the quick expressiveness of awk and Perl.

Comment: Another difference - awk is the only general purpose text processing tool that's mandated by POSIX to exist on all POSIX-compliant Unix systems. The same is not true for perl, python, ruby, etc. but those also aren't peers of awk, they're peers of awk+shell since they can do text manipulation like awk can but they can also do file and process manipulation like shell can and have functionality to do things that several other Unix tools do.

Comment: The big difference between the awk language and the text manipulation language of those other tools is that the awk providers vigorously defend the idea that new language constructs should only be introduced to do things that are hard to do with other existing constructs so awk has a tiny, powerful language to do everything while those other tools have an order of magnitude more language constructs to do almost every unique thing as briefly as possible.

Comment: @dawg some py fun: `for l in open('fn'):open('fn_out','a').write(f"{l[:-9]}{sum(float(x)/60**i for i,x in enumerate(l[-9:-1].split(':'))):.4f}\n")`. Just for the sake of it ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the real amount of conversions (*many thousands*), you could benefit by pre-calculating the decimal parts for all the possible minute-second pairs, storing them to a hash and then fetching and adding them to the hour part:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    for(m=0;m<=59;m++)                                                 # iterate minutes
        for(s=0;s<=59;s++)                                             # iterate seconds
            a[sprintf("%02d:%02d",m,s)]=sprintf("%.4f",(60*m+s)/3600)  # a["01:23"]=.0231
}
{
    print substr($0,1,12) substr($0,13,14)+a[substr($0,16)]            # output in parts
}' file
```

Output on your data:

```
2022 Aug 21 5.5878
2022 Aug 22 14.8925
2022 Aug 31 14.1986
2022 Sep 03 18.4081
2022 Sep 03 18.4156
2022 Sep 04 6.9247
2022 Sep 04 6.9289
2022 Sep 05 16.0325
2022 Sep 05 16.0378
2022 Sep 06 4.3406
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Python, you can setup a dictionary for replacement and avoid calculations entirely during the process:

```
import re
conv = {f":{m:02d}:{s:02d}" : f"{m/60+s/3600:5.4f}"[1:]
        for m in range(60) for s in range(60)}

with open("input.txt") as inFile:
    with open("output.txt",mode="w") as outFile:
        outFile.writelines(re.sub(r":\d\d:\d\d$",lambda m:conv[m.group(0)],s)
                           for s in inFile.readlines() )
```

This processed an input file with 10K lines in 0.018 sec on my laptop (reading and writing on an SSD)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the conversion much more efficiently with Bash code by removing calls to external programs.  This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code demonstrates one way to do it with pure Bash:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

while IFS=$': \t\n' read -r year month day hour min sec || [[ -n $year ]]; do
    printf '%s %s %s %.4f\n' "$year" "$month" "$day"    \
        "$(( ((hour*60 + min)*60 + sec) * 1000000 / 3600 ))e-6"
done </tmp/fn
```

- The code reads input from `/tmp/fn` and writes to standard output.
- See [BashFAQ/001 (How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for explanations of how the `read` loop works.  In particular, see the [My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#My_text_files_are_broken.21__They_lack_their_final_newlines.21) section for an explanation of `|| [[ -n $year ]]`.
- See the (excellent) accepted answer to [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/264812) for an explanation of how the floating point calculation is done.  (The basic idea is to calculate the answer in microhours using integer arithmetic, convert the answer to a literal floating point representation of the number of hours by appending `e-6`, and use the `printf` format string `%.4f` to print it to four decimal places.)
- The code processes an 10K-line input file on my (low-spec) test VM in around 0.3s.  Because of the general extreme slowness of Bash, it's not really practical for significantly larger input files.  You will need to use a more efficient programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I post the `python` code because there is a `python` tag although other languages are mentioned and the example is in bash.

you can convert to `epoch` time like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

dates = [
    '2022 Aug 21 05:35:16',
    '2022 Aug 22 14:53:33',
    '2022 Aug 31 14:11:55', 
    '2022 Sep 03 18:24:29', 
    '2022 Sep 03 18:24:56',
    '2022 Sep 04 06:55:29',
    '2022 Sep 04 06:55:44',
    '2022 Sep 05 16:01:57',
    '2022 Sep 05 16:02:16',
    '2022 Sep 06 04:20:26'
    ]


for d in dates:
    datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S')
    epoch_time = datetime_obj.timestamp()  

    print(epoch_time)
```

which gives this:

```
1661056516.0
1661176413.0
1661951515.0
1662225869.0
1662225896.0
1662270929.0
1662270944.0
1662390117.0
1662390136.0
1662434426.0
```

the advantage of this is that it uses the date part too !!

Comment: The other advantage is it takes 180ms rather than 42 seconds :-)

Comment: This isn't what they're after though -- see the update to the question, where they spell it out

Comment: @zdim,  thanks,  but this answer was posted before the update was made. so it could not have foreseen the update !    the new answer would simply extend on this answer in any event, since the dates are retained.

Comment: "_this answer was posted before the update was made_" -- sure, I saw that, which is why I mentioned the update.  But, then why not edit to actually answer the question?  (Btw, what they wanted could be inferred even before edit I think.)   The problem is that I don't think `strftime` provides for decimal hours so in any case one may be back to doing it by hand

Comment: @zdim,  i have also posted a new answer to resolve the modification to the original question.

Comment: "_posted a new answer_" -- ah, I see. much better :)  I'd suggest to remove this one since it wasn't what they asked

Answer (score 1):

here is the new answer for the modified version of the question. Note that it is similar to the previous answer. The only difference is converting the `hh:mm:ss` part of the string to a decimal.

```py
import datetime

dates = [
    '2022 Aug 21 05:35:16',
    '2022 Aug 22 14:53:33',
    '2022 Aug 31 14:11:55', 
    '2022 Sep 03 18:24:29', 
    '2022 Sep 03 18:24:56',
    '2022 Sep 04 06:55:29',
    '2022 Sep 04 06:55:44',
    '2022 Sep 05 16:01:57',
    '2022 Sep 05 16:02:16',
    '2022 Sep 06 04:20:26'
    ]

for d in dates:
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S") 

    hours = dt.hour
    minutes = dt.minute 
    seconds = dt.second

    decimal_hours = hours + minutes/60 + seconds/3600
    decimal_hours = round(decimal_hours, 4)

    print(dt.strftime("%Y %b %d ") + str(decimal_hours))
```

which produces this:

```
2022 Aug 21 5.5878
2022 Aug 22 14.8925
2022 Aug 31 14.1986
2022 Sep 03 18.4081
2022 Sep 03 18.4156
2022 Sep 04 6.9247
2022 Sep 04 6.9289
2022 Sep 05 16.0325
2022 Sep 05 16.0378
2022 Sep 06 4.3406
```

I would be interested how this python code compares **on time** to the other scripting languages proposed...

Answer (score 0):

```py
d=[
'2022 Aug 21 05:35:16',
'2022 Aug 22 14:53:33',
'2022 Aug 31 14:11:55',
'2022 Sep 03 18:24:29',
'2022 Sep 03 18:24:56',
'2022 Sep 04 06:55:29',
'2022 Sep 04 06:55:44',
'2022 Sep 05 16:01:57',
'2022 Sep 05 16:02:16',
'2022 Sep 06 04:20:26',
]

for i in d:
    timeFormat = i.rsplit(' ', 1)[1].split(':')
    hourFrac = (int(timeFormat[1]) + (int(timeFormat[2])/60)) / 60
    hourFrac = str(hourFrac).replace('0.', '')
    newFormat = str(i.rsplit(' ', 1)[0]) + f" {int(timeFormat[0])}.{hourFrac}"
    print(newFormat)
```

Just threw this together right now. It seems to work.
Output:

```
2022 Aug 21 5.5877777777777777
2022 Aug 22 14.8925
2022 Aug 31 14.1986111111111111
2022 Sep 03 18.40805555555555556
2022 Sep 03 18.41555555555555557
2022 Sep 04 6.9247222222222222
2022 Sep 04 6.9288888888888889
2022 Sep 05 16.0325
2022 Sep 05 16.03777777777777778
2022 Sep 06 4.34055555555555556
```